How to run scheduler job daily with start and end time using AsyncIOScheduler in FastAPI?
I am using FastAPI and using AsyncIOScheduler.
My scheduler condition is: Run the task everyday at 6 am with start_time =6 Am and end time is 8 am.
I have added scheduler code in lifespan in which your code is executed only once when the application started.
Please refer code where I have added datetime.now() to get start and end time but it will execute only once because added it in lifespan so how can I execute job everyday.
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Run at startup
   
    def print_hello():
        print("Hello", datetime.now())
    from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    print("Datetime.......",datetime.now())
    start_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=5)  # Start in 10 seconds
    end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=15)  # End in 60 seconds
    scheduler.add_job(print_hello, "interval", start =start_time, end = end_time, seconds=1)
    scheduler.add_job(print_hello, 'cron', hour=6, minute=0)
    scheduler.start()
    
    yield
    #  Run on shutdown (if required)
    scheduler.shutdown()


You would need to use a cron scheduled job, also known as CronTrigger (the implementation of CronTrigger class can be found here). In this way, the job tiggers when the current time matches all specified time constraints, similarly to how the UNIX cron scheduler works.
As explained in the docs:

You can also specify the starting date and ending dates for the
cron-style schedule through the start_date and end_date
parameters, respectively. They can be given as a date/datetime object
or text (in the ISO 8601 format)
Unlike with crontab expressions, you can omit fields that you don’t
need. Fields greater than the least significant explicitly defined
field default to * while lesser fields default to their minimum values
except for week and day_of_week which default to *. For example,
day=1, minute=20 is equivalent to year='*', month='*', day=1, week='*', day_of_week='*', hour='*', minute=20, second=0. The job will
then execute on the first day of every month on every year at 20
minutes of every hour.

As shown below, you could use a lifespan handler, in order to initialize and start an AsyncIOScheduler (the implementation of AsyncIOScheduler class can be found here), as well as shut it down on application shutdown. In the example below, the cron job should be executed every day at 6:00 a.m.
Working Example
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
from datetime import datetime


def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    trigger = CronTrigger(year="*", month="*", day="*", hour="6", minute="0", second="0")
    scheduler.add_job(tick, trigger)
    scheduler.start()
    yield
    scheduler.shutdown()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get('/')
async def main(request: Request):
    pass

Notes
The below lines in the example above:
trigger = CronTrigger(year="*", month="*", day="*", hour="6", minute="0", second="0")
scheduler.add_job(tick, trigger)

are equivalent to:
scheduler.add_job(tick, "cron", year="*", month="*", day="*", hour="6", minute="6", second="0")

and thus, one could use them interchangeably.
If you had to end the daily job at specific time, you could then have an interval job that is triggered by the cron job every day at 6:00 a.m. and which ends at 8:00 a.m., as mentioned in your question.
Example
def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


def schedule_interval_job(scheduler: AsyncIOScheduler):
    end_date = datetime.now().replace(hour=8, minute=0, second=0)
    scheduler.add_job(tick, "interval", end_date=end_date, seconds=1)  # specify the time interval (seconds) as desired


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(schedule_interval_job, "cron", args=[scheduler], year="*", month="*", day="*", hour="6", minute="0", second="0")
    scheduler.start()
    yield
    scheduler.shutdown()

Alternative solutions to using ApScheduler might be found in this answer.

It is seems a matter of creating a new "interval" scheduled job every day.
And - the best way to do that, is to use a "cron" scheduled job:
You schedule a daily job which will schedule the interval job for that day, on the same scheduler, and forget about it.
Since you are using nested functions inside lifespan itself, the cron job can directly access the scheduler as a nonlocal variable, and you don't even have to worry about passing the scheduler to it as a parameter.
All that said, this should work:
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # prefer adding the "import"s at the module top level, 
    # but if, at function level, always place they first
    from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    # Run at startup
    
    def schedule_daily_interval():
        end_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=8, minute=0, second=0)
        # no need for "start_date" if we are starting right now!
        scheduler.add_job(print_hello, "interval",  end_date = end_time, seconds=1)
        # also, no need to remove the job above after its done:
        # apscheduler does that automatically.
   
    def print_hello():
        print("Hello", datetime.now())
        
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    print("Datetime.......",datetime.now())
    scheduler.add_job(schedule_daily_interval, 'cron', hour=6, minute=0)
    scheduler.start()
    
    yield
    #  Run on shutdown (if required)
    scheduler.shutdown()

Note that although this straight alternative looks fine, for production code you should add some safeguards for several real World scenarios:

If you have more than one FastAPI worker (normally it will run just with one worker, but if if your api is running in some auto- horizontal scaling setup, it could be running in more than one pod. So you might have the job running from more than one worker at the same time - it may or may not make sense - that is up to you

If your FastAPI worker happened to be restarted just at 6:00am or while the job is running, there should be some mechanism to detect that when it comes back online, and resume the job immediately.


